# Euler-Lagrange Equations for charged particle in Einstein notation

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm a math guy, just wanting to clarify some notation. 
[image]

This is the Euler Lagrange equation associated with a charge in an electric field I found in a book. Where $\phi$ and $A$ are the scalar and vector potential related to Maxwell Equations.  I am just curious, this last term, the one with the subscript $j$, is this last term suppose to be a sum over $j=1,2,3$ of that last quantity, i.e it will be three terms? I just wanted clarification for this, since I'm not sure why this sum of omitted if there should be a summation here. If there is not a summation here. Can someone tell me what $j$ is referencing.

I know i is referencing different components of the position vector.

Comment: Yes, it sums over $j = 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Just curious in physics is this omittance of the sum typical? Does the change in subscript over another variable just imply sum?

Comment: Yes, the convention is that any index repeated twice is summed. Also, if it's a regular letter (as opposed to Greek) it's over $1, 2, 3$ instead of $0, 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: The sum is omitted because a lot of equations would become bulky and almost unreadable with all the sums included. Einstein notation is very neat and compact :)

Comment: Actually, beware, because in Special and General relativity, the implicit sum is only for "up-down" indices in tensors. For example, in $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$, there is an implicit sum $\sum_{\mu=1}^4\sum_{\nu=1}^4$. But if you write $F_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$, there is no implicit sum.

Comment: Waouh! I thought there was a mistake but this formula is actually correct: no variation of potential $V$. And the last term with the sum does correspond to $q \vec{\mathbf{v}} \wedge \mathbf{B} =q \vec{\mathbf{v}} \wedge (\mathrm{rot} \mathbf{A})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a small comment, which is to give a name to the notation to possibly help in the future, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Therefore I'm writing this as an answer: Yes, it's extremely powerful, and it's known as the Einstein Summation Convention.  There are nice articles on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) and Wolfram's [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html) on the topic.